# Getting incorrect values from Simple arithmethic in Python

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial by Coding Train wherein we have to make a simple perceptron that identifies whether a point is above or below a line.

The constructor of my Perceptron class creates 2 random weights using `numpy.random.uniform` function, 
Then we have the guess function that takes in a list `inputs` with the `(x,y)` coordinates of the point.

The formula is

> (w1 * input1) + (w2 * input2)

then my sign function makes the output to be only either a 1 or  a -1

if the result of that formula is `>= 0` then the output will be 1 else it will be -1

```py
import numpy

# activation function
def sign(n):
    if n <  0:
        return -1
    else: 
        return 1


class Perceptron:

    def __init__(self):
        self.weights = [0.0, 0.0]

        # initialize the weights randomly
        for i in self.weights:
            # generate a random weight
            # from -1 to 1
            i = numpy.random.uniform(-1, 1)
            print('weights: ', i)


    def guess(self, inputs):
        sum = 0.0

        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            print('inputs: ', inputs[i])
            print('formula: ', inputs[i] * self.weights[i])
            sum += inputs[i] * self.weights[i]
            print('sum', sum)

        output = sign(sum)
        print('Output: ', output)
        return output
```

The inputs is hardcoded for testing `inputs = [-1, -0.5]`

In the output below the formula should be:

> sum = (0.6628487604118101 * -1) + (0.44508063558107414 * -0.5)
>   sum = -0.66284876041 + -0.22254031779
>   sum = -0.8853890782

so since it's less than 0 the output must be `-1`

This is the output when I try to run it, I used a few prints to decode the program but I don't know why I always get 1.

```sh
$ python main.py
weights:  0.6628487604118101
weights:  0.44508063558107414
inputs:  -1
formula:  -0.0
sum 0.0
inputs:  -0.5
formula:  -0.0
sum 0.0
Output: 1
```

Comment: Assigning to a loop variable doesn't assign to a list cell. Your weights are all 0.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment already pointed out, your weight assignment code does not actually assign the weights. They are lost when the loop is left.

This (probably not very efficient) snippet might do what you want to achieve:

```
numWeights = 2
weights = []
for i in range(numWeights):
  w = numpy.random.uniform(-1, 1)
  weights.append(w)
  print('weight:', w)
```